# android: Project.Properties - do not edit, your changes will be erased?

Tags: android, project-properties

I seem to have an issue.

I wanted to add some additional config info into project.properties in an android project but i notice when i open it there are comments telling me not to edit it

Is it safe to edit

Would it get regenerated at some point so i would lose my changes?

Is there an alternative?

**EDIT**

Somebody suggested looking here https://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html

which states

> project.properties This file contains project settings, such as the
>   build target. This file is integral to the project, so maintain it in
>   a source revision control system. To edit project properties in
>   Eclipse, right-click the project folder and select Properties.

but i found no reference at all about editing properties in eclipse

Any ideas?

it seems google thinks you should be able to do it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please see [this](https://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html) info. The project.properties file should be edited using eclipse. Select project -> properties -> Android.

Comment: in my eclipse i don't see any way of editing the project.properties in the properties dialog

Comment: There is no direct way of editing - do you see settings like this: http://goo.gl/E1ZyJ ?

Comment: If you have no "Android" entry in the list on the left you eclipse is not configured for Android development or you are browsing project setting for something which is not an android project.

Comment: Yes i see settings like that (with android on the right), also i created the android project through the template of eclipse... But i don't see anywhere where i can edit the project.properties..

Comment: As I have been trying to tell you .. you do not edit project.properties directly. You use Eclipse/ADT. It will generate/update project.properties for you based on your input to the different dialogs like selecting what version to build for (AFAIK).

Comment: This doesn't tell us anything about how to add things to `project.properties`. For example, I want to add `manifestmerger.enabled=true` to mine. This dialog is useless for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can **Go on to Save the content** of the `project.properties` as it is somewhere on your **PC** and go on to play with it as you Like.
If you find problem after **Editing** it,You can Always go on to **re-place** it with the Saved file and clean the project once.
It will always fix your problem.