# How to set Android SDK target in Worklight Studio

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

I just installed a new Worklight 6.1 environment (Studio).
I got a brand new Eclipse 4.3.1 and installed Worklight 6.1 plugin on top of that. 
Then I downloaded Android SDK and Tools.
When I created my first sample project and added Android environment, automatically the tool set the Android target SDK to 19, which I actually I don't have installed, so I got an error.

I then changed the following line in AndroidManifest.xml to my desired target SDK:

`<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" android:targetSdkVersion="15"/>`

but building Android environment, I receive following message:

> It is recommended that your Android application will target the same API level used to build the android project. The API 
>   level used to compile the project is specified as the Project Build Target in Project / Properties / Android dialog. Configure your application 
>   to target the same API level by setting the same value in android:targetSdkVersion attribute in AndroidManifest.xml.

So it seems that changing the target SDK in AndroidManifest.xml is not enough, but I can't find this :   Project Build Target in Project / Properties / Android dialog.

Any advice is most welcome.

Giovanni

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Project Build target you are referring to appears in the properties of the Android project and not the Worklight project.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Alternative, you may update in the main project
`apps/appName/android/native/project.properties`.
You'll also need to take care of `AndroidManifest.xml`.

`project.properties` has this contradictory notice ([as pointed out by this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11626545/android-project-properties-do-not-edit-your-changes-will-be-erased)), but it is safe to edit it.

```
# This file is automatically generated by Android Tools.
# Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!
# 
# This file must be checked in Version Control Systems.
```